# rsync troubles: not ignoring directories as expected

Tags: command-line, bash, backup, rsync

I know rsync has a man page, but yet is quite hard to digest (I've tried it).

So I came up with this command to sync my data to /Backup in an external drive:

```bsh
sudo rsync -aAXv --delete --exclude={'/home/eoan/.audacity_data','/home/eoan/.cargo','/home/eoan/.cache','/home/eoan/.node_repl_history','/home/eoan/.npm','/home/eoan/.pki','/home/eoan/.pybel','/home/eoan/.ssr','/home/eoan/VirtualBox_VMs','**/node_modules','/home/eoan/VirtualBoxMS'} /home/eoan/ /media/eoan/Backup/
```

Now I will a short version, but logically equivalent:

```bsh
sudo rsync -aAXv --delete --exclude={'/home/eoan/.cargo','/home/eoan/.cache','**/node_modules'} /home/eoan/ /media/eoan/Backup/
```

Rsync isn't ignoring any of those folders, would you please give me a hand
to spot the error?

---

I include a `ls -a` on the backup directory (part of it):

```
.cache          .icons            .profile            .viminfo
.cargo          .lesshst          .pybel              .vimrc
.config         .local            .python_history     VirtualBoxMS
```

Comment: try it without the = (equals) sign. Myself, I don't know about the brackets, I use a separate --exclude per directive.

Comment: Patterns starting with "`/`" are treated as rooted at the "root of the transfer" (unless it's a per-directory rule, in which case they're rooted at that directory. Since the transfer is rooted at `/home/eoan`, `--exclude='/home/eoan/.cache'` is actually going to exclude `/home/eoan/home/eoan/.cache`. So try just `--exclude='/.cache'` etc. I don't see a problem with the `'**/node_modules'` exclusion (though I'm not an expert at this either); does that one work? If I understand correctly, you could change it to just `--exclude='node_modules'` and get the same effect.

Comment: No, the node modules is being included, and it's a bunch of huge folders :-(...thanks for the corrections though @GordonDavisson

Comment: @DougSmythies thanks, though I find it easier that way, and it should be possible!! :-(